# Не обновляются данные в БД Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Создал таблицу

```sql
CREATE TABLE post (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    data TIMESTAMP
);
```

Хочу ее обновить и не могу понять, почему не меняется поле `name`. Как бы ни менял синтаксис запроса, поле никак не хочет меняться, а в консоли все меняется. В чем причина?

```java
public void update(Post posts) {
    String sql = "UPDATE post" + "SET name = ?" + "WHERE id = ?";
    try (Connection cn = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, posts.getName());
        ps.setInt(2, 0);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Post {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private LocalDate create;
    
    public Post(String name, int id, String desc, LocalDate create) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.create = create;
    }
    
    public Post() {}
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
    public LocalDate getCreate() {
        return create;
    }
    
    public void setCreate(LocalDate create) {
        this.create = create;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Post post = (Post) o;
        return id == post.id && Objects.equals(name, post.name) 
                && Objects.equals(desc, post.desc) 
               && Objects.equals(create, post.create);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, desc, create);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
               "id=" + id +
               ", name= '" + name + '\'' +
               ", desc= '" + desc + '\'' +
               ", create= " + create +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему `ps.setInt(2, 0);` у вас id всегда равен нулю ?

Comment: А еще странно, вот в строке `String sql = "UPDATE post" + "SET name = ?" + "WHERE id = ?";` перед SET и WHERE откуда пробелы берутся ? что то мне подсказывает что у вас строка выходит "... postSET name = ?WHERE ...". Зачем вы строку вообще через + формируете из кусков, просто что бы дольше работало и было потенциально больше ошибок ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно устранить следующие ошибки в представленном коде

1. Исправить синтаксис SQL-запроса, в котором не хватает пробелов перед `SET` и `WHERE`, убрав совершенно ненужную конкатенацию.
2. Обеспечить установку корректного идентификатора
3. Вызвать метод [`PreparedStatement::executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()), который отвечает за выполнение запроса на сервере базы данных, одного создания объекта типа `PreparedStatement` недостаточно.

```java
public void update(Post posts) {
    String sql = "UPDATE post SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
    try (Connection cn = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, posts.getName());
        ps.setInt(2, posts.getId()); // подставить нужный id
        int n = ps.executeUpdate();  // выполнить UPDATE запрос
        System.out.println("Количество обновлённых строк: " + n);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ , забыл про executeUpdte поэтому не обновлялись данные.